# Swashbuckle IDocumentFilter implementation - how to link the ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo to the Operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

- Project: ASP Net Core 2.2, Web API
- Packages: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (4.0.1)

I am writing an implementation `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IDocumentFilter` which adds x-summary value at the path level in my swagger config file.  To do this it needs access to the following two pieces of information for each web method

1. ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo - to get access to attributes on the method
2. Operation.Summary - the method's Xml comment

It seems I can get #1 from the `context` and #2 from the `swaggerDoc` that are supplied to the IDocumentFilter implementation, but I can't find a nice way to link them except for using the path.

Is there a neater way ?

An simplified example of what I am doing is below.

```
public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
{
  // Create a map from path (prepended with "/") to the custom attribute
  var methodsByPath = context.ApiDescriptions
    .ToDictionary(
      m => $"/{m.RelativePath}",
      m => ((ControllerActionDescriptor)m.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyCustomAttribute>());

  // Add x-summary to each path
  foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths)
  {
    var customAttribute = methodsByPath[pathItem.Key];

    pathItem.Value.Extensions["x-summary"]
      = GeneratePathDescription(pathItem.Value.Post.Summary, customAttribute);
  }
}

string GeneratePathDescription(string methodSummary, MyCustomAttribute attr)
{
  [snip]
}
```

Comment: nice, do you know how to change order of controllers? i put CustomDocumentFilter with resorted `swaggerDoc.Paths`, but it works only if SwaggerTag controller attribute is not present... if present such sorting does not have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation looks pretty neat to me, but If you are looking for examples of how to "best" implement an IDocumentFilter look in the code of Swashbuckle:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/e2f30e04f412b821a5a989338a186e422c776cc4/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/AnnotationsDocumentFilter.cs

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/b64b8fd6fbc7959849445be676f5e3d4a8e947bf/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/XmlComments/XmlCommentsDocumentFilter.cs