# Swashbuckle Override Route Name in Documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, customization, swashbuckle

I need to display a custom route name for a controller action in the Swagger documentation but I can't use the official [Route] attribute to achieve this.

So I have put together a SwaggerRouteNameFilter and Attribute. However, when
I try changing the route name, it does not reflect in the documentation. Am I missing something?

Note: Using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.1.5 in an Asp.Net Core 5 project.

```
public class SwaggerRouteNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public SwaggerRouteNameAttribute(string maskedRouteName)
    {
        Name = maskedRouteName;
    }
}
public class SwaggerRouteNameFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Parameters ??= new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        if (context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SwaggerRouteNameAttribute)) is SwaggerRouteNameAttribute customAttribute)
        {
            context.ApiDescription.RelativePath = "/test/test2/3";
            context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template = "/test/test2/3";

            // Even when setting the route via reflection, it still does not display in swagger docs
            try
            {
                var myclass = ((RouteAttribute)context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata[12]); //NB update your route location index!
                var field = typeof(RouteAttribute).GetField("<Template>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                field.SetValue(myclass, "/test/test2/3");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Startup code

```
// startup.cs 
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.OperationFilter<SwaggerRouteNameFilter>();
}
```

Sample controller using custom attribute and custom controller name

```
[ControllerName("Authorisation")] // overrides the name of this faux controller
public class Faux1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/faux/route/1")]
    [SwaggerRouteName("connect/authorize")]
    public IActionResult GetResult()
    {
        return Ok();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hey mate - as per [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/361) not sure it's possible using an operation filter. There's a few clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569007/swashbuckle-idocumentfilter-implementation-how-to-link-the-actiondescriptor-me) on how you might use IDocumentFilter though

Comment: Tnx dude. I'll check it out and report back if a find a solution.

Comment: Tnx @fuzzy-logic. I got it working using IDocumentFilter. I ran into the same problem as the gentlemen in that bug report you shared with me, whereby the Swagger UI/json needs to be requested twice before the route path change actually reflects. I've logged a bug with the Swashbuckle about it.